# C++ method inheritance with return type depending on class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Food
{
public:
    Food * copy() const
    {
        return new Food(*this);
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```

And I want it to be the base class for other classes which would inherit the `copy` method. I would have to write it manually every time:

```
class Cheese: public Food
{
public:
    Cheese * copy() const
    {
        return new Cheese(*this);
    }
    .
    .
    .
};

class Bread: public Food
{
public:
    Bread * copy() const
    {
        return new Bread(*this);
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```

etc. How to solve that problem? I'm thinking of templates, but I'm still not sure how to use them... Here is the program I made, and it won't compile:

```
#include <cstring>

template <class T>

class Food
{
protected:
    double weight;
public:
    T * copy() { return new T(*this); }
    Food(){ weight = 1; }
    Food(const Food& f){ weight = f.weight; }
};

class Cheese : public Food<Cheese>
{
    char * color;
public:
    Cheese(const char * c)
    {
        color = new char[strlen(c)+1];
        strcpy(color,c);
    }
    Cheese(const Cheese& c)
    {
        weight = c.weight;
        color = new char[strlen(c.color)+1];
        strcpy(color,c.color);
    }
};

main()
{
    Cheese first("yellow");
    Cheese * second = first.copy();
}
```

And here are the errors:

```
|10|error: no matching function for call to ‘Cheese::Cheese(Food<Cheese>&)’|
|10|note: candidates are:|
|24|note: Cheese::Cheese(const Cheese&)|
|24|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Food<Cheese>’ to ‘const Cheese&’|
|19|note: Cheese::Cheese(const char*)|
|19|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Food<Cheese>’ to ‘const char*’|
||In member function ‘T* Food<T>::copy() [with T = Cheese]’:|
|10|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it

```
T * copy() { return new T(*static_cast<T*>(this)); }
```

In `Food<T>::copy`, 'this' is `Food<T>*`, while you need a `T*`.

Comment: is it the same as  return new T( * (T*) this);  ?

Comment: In this particular example, yes. But it would do a wrong thing if someone (perhaps by mistake) writes, say, `class Foo : public Food<Bar> {...}`. `static_cast` will refuse to cast between pointers to unrelated classes - you'll see an error - but C-style cast will happily go ahead, producing an invalid pointer and likely crashing at run time.

Comment: Another question, what if I want to have another class which would inherit `Cheese`? `class Cheese : public Food<Cheese>` ok, but what if I want Mozzarella to inherit `Cheese`? `class Mozzarella : public Cheese<Mozzarella>` wont work.

Comment: Not unless you make `Cheese` itself a template. Which is why you don't see such fancy solutions in practice very often - they are difficult to generalize to an arbitrary class hierarchy.

Comment: Yep, so the best solution in this case is not to use templates, but to write methods manually... thanks